# Recyclerview animation

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview

The problem is when I scroll up the `recyclerview` it overlapped. Should I disable the animation when I scroll? how?

Animation code inside my `viewholder`:

```
int lastPosition = -1;
  Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(HomeActivity.this,
    (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.up_from_bottom: R.anim.down_from_top);
     holder.itemView.startAnimation(animation);
     lastPosition = position;
```

anim : up from button

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="400" />
```

anim: down from bottom

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="-100%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="400" />
```

Comment: I need something like what google newstand does